# Solving Linear equation in R

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, covariance, linear-equation

Is there a way to compute correlation of U = 2X1 − X2 and V = X1 + 2X2 using R (not manually) given the variance of X1, variance of X2 and Covariance between X1 and X2?

Answer (score 3):

The covariance matrix of two random variables is the 2x2 symmetric matrix whose diagonals are the variances of the two components and whose off-diagonal elements are the covariances.   That is, if the variances of X1 and X2 were v1 and v2 and the covariance v12 then the covariance matrix of X would be `matrix(c(v1, v12, v12, v2), 2)`. We can readily form a covariance matrix via `cov(d)` where `d` is a two column matrix of data.  To be concrete let us the form the covariance matrix of the builtin two column data frame `BOD`.  Then we can use the formula below to get the covariance matrix of the transformation and use `cov2cor` to get the correlation matrix.  The upper (and also by symmetry the lower) off-diagonal element of the correlation matrix will be the desired correlation.  No packages are used.

```
# inputs: covariance matrix V and transformation matrix M
V <- cov(BOD)
M <- matrix(c(2, 1, -1, 2), 2)

cov2cor(M %*% V %*% t(M))[1, 2]
## [1] -0.3023
```

To double check transform `BOD` using `M` and then calculate the correlation of that.   We see that the result is the same.

```
cor(as.matrix(BOD) %*% t(M))[1, 2]
## [1] -0.3023
```